# How did we figure out what resistance was?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors, history

We were able to figure out that every material offered some resistance.

And we were also able to figure out that there is a constant between current and voltage at a specific temperate.

But how did we figure out that the *constant* **was** resistance?
In short,

How did we connect the constant between voltage and current and the phenomenon of resistance.

How can we prove that the ratio of voltage and current is infact resistance.

What made us think that

--> [Phenomenon of Resistance] =R = V/I

Because that ratio could have been just a normal constant. What was the reason for calling a mere constant resistance?

Comment: What do you think resistance is besides the name given to that particular constant after the constant was already identified.

Comment: I think resistance is the opposition to the motion of electron. Which I understand. But how did we connect "resistance" and the constant between voltage and current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1827 [Georg Ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Ohm) established that the current through a conducting wire with a fixed EMF across its ends decreased in proportion with the length of the wire, but increased in proportion with the wire's cross-sectional area (or, equivalently, the number of identical wires connected in parallel). Since the wire appeared to *resist* the flow of current through it, it was natural to call this property of the wire's material its "resistivity" $\rho$, and then to call the property $\rho \frac l A$ of a particular piece of wire its "resistance" $R$.

It was not known at the time *why or how* a wire resisted the passage of current through it, or why different materials had different resistivities, or why resistivity varied with temperature. In fact, until J.J. Thomson showed that the electron was an individual particle in 1897, it was thought that electrical current was the flow of some sort of continuous fluid. But "resistance" was simply a convenient label for whatever it was that "resisted" the flow of electricity through a wire.

Answer (score 2):

The "constant" which was already identified for different materials in experiments was infact named resistance, and for the intuition of constants for different materials, consider two materials with different resistances $R_1$ and $R_2$ , note as ohm's law was found experimentally, apply same voltage $V$ across these two materials, now the experimental equations will be as following

V=$I_1R_1$

V=$I_2R_2$

Notice Here as $V$ is constant in both equations , greater is the exprimental constant for a material, less is the current compared to other material,In other sense, this constant acted as "RESISTANCE" in flow of current, hence this term was undeniably termed as resistance